# Dialing TCP Error: Timeout or i/o Timeout after a while of high concurrency request

Tags: http, go, tcp, concurrency, timeout

I recently run into a problem when I develope a high concurrency http client via `valyala/fasthttp`: The client works fine in the first 15K~ requests but after that more and more `dial tcp4 127.0.0.1:80: i/o timeout` and `dialing to the given TCP address timed out` error occours.

#### Sample Code

```
var Finished = 0
var Failed = 0
var Success = 0

func main() {
    for i := 0; i < 1000; i++ {
        go get()
    }
    start := time.Now().Unix()
    for {
        fmt.Printf("Rate: %.2f/s Success: %d, Failed: %d\n", float64(Success)/float64(time.Now().Unix()-start), Success, Failed)
        time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond)
    }
}

func get() {
    ticker := time.NewTicker(time.Duration(100+rand.Intn(2900)) * time.Millisecond)
    defer ticker.Stop()
    client := &fasthttp.Client{
        MaxConnsPerHost: 10000,
    }
    for {
        req := &fasthttp.Request{}
        req.SetRequestURI("http://127.0.0.1:80/require?number=10")
        req.Header.SetMethod(fasthttp.MethodGet)
        req.Header.SetConnectionClose()
        res := &fasthttp.Response{}
        err := client.DoTimeout(req, res, 5*time.Second)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err.Error())
            Failed++
        } else {
            Success++
        }
        Finished++
        client.CloseIdleConnections()
        <-ticker.C
    }
}
```

#### Detail

The server is built on `labstack/echo/v4` and when client got timeout error, the server didn't have any error, and manually perform the request via `Postman` or Browser like `Chrome` are works fine.

The client runs pretty well in the first 15K~ request, but after that, more and more timeout error occours and the output `Rate` is decreasing. I seached for google and github and I found this [issue](https://github.com/valyala/fasthttp/issues/656) may be the most suitable one, but didn't found a solution.

##### Another tiny problem...

As you can notice, when the client start, it will first generate some `the server closed connection before returning the first response byte. Make sure the server returns 'Connection: close' response header before closing the connection` error, and then works fine till around 15K issues, and then start generating more and more timeout error.Why it would generate the Connection closed error in the begining?

#### Machine Info

Macbook Pro 14 2021 (Apple M1 Pro) with 16GB Ram and running macOS Monterey 12.4

Comment: I'm not sure what you expected, you are trying to get 1000 clients to connect and disconnect as rapidly as possible. This is extremely inefficient, and you're going to quickly be throttled by the operating systems running out of ports. You also have data races in your program, so the actual numbers you see can't be valid.

Comment: @JimB Thanks, my lack of baisc network knowledege cause this problem~ After tring to reuse a connection as possible, Im getting much higher result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically, If you trying to open a connection and then close it as soon as possibile, it's not going to be like "connection#1 use a port then immediately return it back", there gonna be lots of processing needs to be done, so If you want to send many request at the same time, I think it's better to reuse the connection as possible as you can.

For example, in `fasthttp`:

```golang
req := fasthttp.AcquireRequest()
res := fasthttp.AcquireResponse()
defer fasthttp.ReleaseRequest(req)
defer fasthttp.ReleaseResponse(res)

// Then do the request below
```